# Function for inserting/updating MySql DB returns wrong "affected rows" number

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using the code below to insert or update a `MySql` table using values from a `DataTable`

```
Function DB_Multi_Ins_Or_Upd_From_DT(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal DestTbl$) As Integer
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(CnStr) 
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            Dim CmdTxt$ = "INSERT INTO " & DestTbl & " ("
            For Each Col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                CmdTxt &= Col.ColumnName & ", "
            Next
            CmdTxt = CmdTxt.Substring(0, CmdTxt.Length - 2) & ") VALUES ("
            For x As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                For xx As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    CmdTxt &= "@" & "R" & x.ToString & "C" & xx.ToString & ", "
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue _
                        ("@" & "R" & x.ToString & "C" & xx.ToString, dt.Rows(x)(xx))
                Next xx
                CmdTxt = CmdTxt.Substring(0, CmdTxt.Length - 2) & "), ("
            Next x
            CmdTxt = CmdTxt.Substring(0, CmdTxt.Length - 3)
            CmdTxt &= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
            For Each Col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                CmdTxt &= Col.ColumnName & "=VALUES(" & Col.ColumnName & "), "
            Next
            CmdTxt = CmdTxt.Substring(0, CmdTxt.Length - 2)
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = CmdTxt
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                Dim AffRows% = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Return AffRows
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                Return -1
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

It happens that the code updates 1 row but returns 2.

Edit: It seems that the wrong result is returned only on `update` while on `insert` is returned the right number of affected rows

What's wrong? How can I fix and get rigth number of affected rows?

> Edit: To test my code it needs:
>
> 1) Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
>
> 2) give a value to `cnstr` like
>       "datasource=" + Server_Name + ";username= " + UserDB + ";password="
>       + Password + ";database=" + Database_Name + ""
>
> 3) create a `DataTable` who has column names like fields of a DB table
>
> 4) call the function passing the DataTable and the name of the table
>   on the DB

Comment: Can you show your update code then?

Comment: @Steve What do you mean? To update I use the function posted passing a DataTable to it. This is my code. When a row alredy exists it will be updated

Comment: Sorry, missed the 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' See answer from the MySQL documentation below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and
>   0 if an existing row is set to its current values

[dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: So I'll never be able to know the effective number of affected rows! If 4 is returned it's possible that two rows were updated, or 4 rows were inserted, or 1 row was updated and two were inserted? Is there a way to get detailed informations?

Comment: Sure, don't use that function but instead write either an update or insert sql statement. That will get you the right number.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft

> When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value (of ExecuteNonQuery) includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers

So, either it's double-counting your affected rows, or you're actually updating 2 rows.

Comment: I don't have any trigger and it seems that wrong number is returned only on updates